# Offensive message by a moderator not being taken in consideration

Tags: support

A moderator posted this message

> That could be because - unfortunately - such naivety is very common
> with 'developers' from that area.

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/18684590#18684590

as response to

> someone comes and asks about JS and Java, someone guesses that he is
> Indian because of his naivity and noone does anything

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/18684575#18684575

Now, this is highly offensive to Indian users isn't it?

Shouldn't disciplinary action be taken against this moderator? In my opinion he should be the first person to give the example. I'm not Indian myself so it's nothing to do with patriotism, and the message is clear.

Comment: Adam: So you got muted in JS chat. Get over it. Calling rlemon names in different chats and posting stuff like this is _really_ not working in your favor.

Comment: @Cerbrus What has that to do with the question? care to explain? I got muted as a result of reporting this moderator's message, that's all.

Comment: Read in context it looks like the moderator made an observation based on his experience. It isn't insulting or offensive, it is just an observation.

Comment: Well, you stated a correlation was observed, and the response you quote stated the correlation was correct, except better stated in the opposite direction

Comment: @JayBlanchard *That could be because - unfortunately - such naivety is very common with 'developers' from that area.* How is that not offensive? he's saying something based on his racial preference, because I assure you there are even equal naivety amongst german developers. No need to generalize

Comment: @JayBlanchard "Not all the truth is good to say" - Anyway, isn't it some sort of private chat ? It doesn't seem to be public (I don't know much about chats)

Comment: @AdamBarak It's very easily not offensive. I didn't get offended when I read it, for example.

Comment: "such naivety is very common with 'developers' from that area" I think the statement would be more truthful if we remove the last three words.

Comment: @Clive I think you're either not Indian or you're afraid of the community bashing if you take the right stance.

Comment: It isn't offensive *at all*. People make observations, based on experience, all of the time. Are your observations offensive @AdamBarak?

Comment: Maybe I should start getting offended when I see someone say _"All dutch wear wooden shoes and smoke weed"_

Comment: I'm not Indian, no. Neither are you, you said so in your question. So your taking offence to this is somehow more valid than my not taking offence, because...please enlighten me. Also, if the comment had been in response to talking about German developers, would you still be calling it 'offensive'?

Comment: @AwalGarg Exactly. He's saying that **especially** naivety is common among Indians.

Comment: Well, a user called ziGi got suspended for saying he thought I looked like an Israeli businessman, where in fact I even was ok with that. Why do we have to take exception? or we suspend both moderators and users saying that or we don't either.

Comment: No, he's not. He's saying that __that specific naivety__ is common.

Comment: Now @Cerbrus why would you be offended about the wooden shoe thing? ;)

Comment: @AdamBarak no, he is saying that he thinks so. He can think whatever he wants...

Comment: Is it perfectly valid to say "czech beers are the best", but offensive to say "german beers are worse than czech beers"? I'd say not.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I always wear wooden shoes to work. My computer here is powered by a windmill. :-)

Comment: @AdamBarak: Did the user get a temporary site ban, or did they receive a *chat ban only*. Because the latter only takes *regular chatters* to enact and is very temporary. **And it doesn't mean it as for just that one message**. If they received a site-wide temporary ban, then that takes a moderator and there would have been *far more* going on than just that message.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The user message was flagged and successfully removed, ThiefMaster's didn't. That is the difference I want to know. He was suspended from chat for that and other reasons. The fact is that message was comprised and I was ok with the fact he said that to me

Comment: @AdamBarak: that's **very simple** then. You are looking at a private conversation between 2 people. No one flagged the message because **no one cared**. The other message was in a public chat room with far more exposure. The people in the chatroom cared, and they flagged the message. The message could have been 'flatirons are crummy'; if enough people *in the chatroom* think it should be flagged, the user posted that message gets a temporary ban.

Comment: @AdamBarak are you complaining that the mod's message (whom you've just (accidentally?) named) didn't get deleted, or that yours did?

Comment: zigi's case is complex and wide enough. Debatting this ban here only messes this question.

Comment: @dystroy downvotes are the least problem really. but if we should act on a user we should also do that on a moderator.

Comment: What the blazes were you even doing in that room in the first place? That was a one-on-one conversation.

Comment: @AdamBarak `Exactly. He's saying that **especially** naivety is common among Indians. ` Not true. He is saying that a *certain type* of naivety is *commonly* displayed , not that "all Indians are naive". Very different.

Comment: @MartijnPieters What changes between the fact that it's in a private room or public room? isn't the content the same anyway?

Comment: @AdamBarak did you flag the mod's message? Did the flag get handled? How?

Comment: @JanDvorak I flagged it but I guess it got rejected as it's still there

Comment: @AdamBarak: This has **nothing to do with content** and everything with context. You are quite happily ignoring the context here, which makes me think you are deliberately looking to stir trouble.

Comment: @Cerbrus I was talking to zigi outside of this site and he told me to check that room out about ThiefMaster message espcieally

Comment: So, then Zigi should've flagged the message, if he felt offended.

Comment: @Cerbrus Perhaps he did, but at this rate I'm sure it would get declined, because it isn't offensive.

Answer (score 31):

Let's bring the whole context here. A repeat offender in the JS room posted a message people considered offensive. They proceeded to attempt to provoke other users just to get 'stuff' to talk about on meta. You can read the whole discussion in the room.

You're attempting to "Punish" a diamond moderator for not agreeing with you. More than that - taking the time to try to reason with you personally and explain how the system works is absurd. Be grateful that people are taking the time and trying to help you with the system rather than trying really hard to annoy those people.

ThiefMaster said before:

> Then THAT SOMEONE can flag if he feels offended. Also, calling someone a racial slur is a different thing than calling someone annoying.
>
> It's a chat. Of course jokes between people who know each other since some time are something else than a joke from someone who's generally considered annoying.

There is a diamond moderator, as well as a SE staff member who are aware of this. There is no community discussion required here.

Comment: Also, this was in a semi-private channel.

Comment: Pft. There is no internet privacy anymore.

Comment: ++ and [what's that smell?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/57/reversal)

Comment: @SterlingArcher http://www.chatcrypt.com/

Comment: I stand corrected!

Comment: @SterlingArcher: http://www.crypho.com/ Disclaimer: I used to work with the people that built that.

Comment: @SterlingArcher https://crypto.cat/

Comment: -1 This does not address the question at all. The actions of some other user are irrelevant. The moderator's response is a sweeping generalization and is offensive. SE Moderator's should know how to act.

Comment: @jliv902 You was unfortunately the only one to understand this. Thank you. Kudos to you

Comment: @jliv902 it's taken completely out of context. Read the whole discussion.